# Nested functions;.todays(datediff(student_info,'1999-8-31'))

Tags: php

im new to sql and php. I want to calculate age of a student(in months) by the differentia of dob(table field) and fixed date(;. 31-8-2016). and also want to store that value in the field named 'age'

Comment: then why don't you just do it?

Comment: Maybe something like this, not test and not even sure if it is correct :) - `INSERT INTO table ( age ) VALUES ( SELECT DATEDIFF( DATE_FORMAT( '2016-08-31', %Y-%m-%d ), DATE_FORMAT( (SELECT dob FROM students WHERE id = 1), %Y-%m-%d ) ) ); `

Answer (score 0):

> USING MYSQL

```
SELECT 12 * (YEAR(DateOfService) 
              - YEAR(BirthDate)) 
       + (MONTH(DateOfService) 
           - MONTH(BirthDate)) AS months 
FROM table
```

> USING PHP

```
$date1 = '2000-01-25';
$date2 = '2010-02-20';

$ts1 = strtotime($date1);
$ts2 = strtotime($date2);

$year1 = date('Y', $ts1);
$year2 = date('Y', $ts2);

$month1 = date('m', $ts1);
$month2 = date('m', $ts2);

$diff = (($year2 - $year1) * 12) + ($month2 - $month1);
```

Comment: Thanks. It was really helpful. can you please tell me how can I use IF statement on months(by sql statement or HP). Actually i want to assign grades in a drop down or text box on the base of calculated months.  For example " If months <=43 then 'PG'   else If months >=44 and months <= 55 then 'YN'.......so on